# AWS device farm audio injection

Tags: appium-ios, aws-device-farm, python-appium

I'm currently developing a web app in which there is an voice integration with the user.
I'm testing this web app using AWS device farm on appium-python.
There is a way to inject audio into the device and play it at specific time?

At the moment i couldn't find any solution regarding how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

We found a turn around solution at the moment.
Instead of mocking the microphone, we are mocking a function that handles with the audio file using execute_script() function.